# Wrapping ISDATE calculated column with IFERROR (Sharepoint Online)

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

Currently, have a calculated column that calculates the difference in days between 2 date columns.

```
=DATEDIF([Issue Date],[Due Date],"d")
```

When there is no value entered or an incorrect value entered, it displays as "#Name?"

Tried wrapping IFERROR around it but not sure on the syntax.

**Current syntax:**

```
=DATEDIF(ISERROR(([Issue Date],[Due Date],"d")),"",([Issue Date],[Due Date],"d"))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
=IF(ISERROR(DATEDIF([Start Date],[Due Date],"d")),"",DATEDIF([Start Date],[Due Date],"d"))
```

You will need to add IF condition to evaluate ISERROR return value which True or False.  More details [here](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/IS-functions-586532cc-9888-4ca0-98b8-c874e4c8a087)

Comment: Works perfectly, much obliged. So for something similar using a different error condition, would you always wrap it in an IF first off, before inserting your IS condition?